# Posting Large Data Forms Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, post, 2-way-object-databinding

I have been racking my brain for hours on this project.  I have been searching through JSON, watching youtube videos, and searching on here for answers and still can not figure this out.  I'm trying to post data into a table, using javascript objects.  When it comes to posting smaller data to a table, I can do that, but not sure why I can't work with multiple objects, that are nested.

**EDIT:** 
The problem currently is that it is not posting the data in the submission form to the table when the submit button.  I want to be able to add multiple entries into the table, then later add quotes and proposals.

Other aspects that would be bonus is explaining working with these types of data that contain multiple javascript objects and working with those using angular.  Most documents and apis pull for one object, but not nested objects.

If you could explain why it isn't working, and let me know if this is a correct method for event attempting it.  http://codepen.io/ddavisgraphics/pen/LExGNB?editors=101  Link to the codepen.

**Javascript**

```
(function () {

    // start the app 
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller("CustomerCtrl", function () {
        // Pull in the Customers 
        this.customers = customerArray;
        // Create New Customers 
        this.newCustomer = {};

        this.AddCustomer = function(newCust) {
            this.customers.push({
                customer: newCust.customer,
                phone: newCust.phone,
                email: newCust.email,
                // start address strings 
                address: {
                    line1: newCust.line1,
                    city: newCust.city,
                    state: newCust.state,
                    zip: newCust.zip,
                },
            });
            console.log(customerArray); 
            //console.log(this.newCustomer); 
        };

    });


    var customerArray = [
    // Start Customer  
    {
        customer: "John Franklin",
        phone: "555.555.5551",
        email: "jfranklin@franks.com",
        // start address strings 
        address: {
            line1: "Road or Po Box",
            city: "Glenvilles",
            state: "West Carolina",
            zip: 45648,
        },
        proposals: [{
            project_title: "Project Title",
            type: "Graphic Design",
            deadline: "Jan. 2, 2015",
            delivery_type: "files",
            problem: "The problem is that the customer has too much crap.",
            notes: "Wants to keep the neon pink color scheme"
        }, {
            project_title: "Project Title II",
            type: "Web Design",
            deadline: "Jan. 22, 2015",
            delivery_type: "online",
            problem: "Another prject",
            notes: "Wants neon green with the neon pink on a digital screen"
        }],
        quotes: [{
            quote_num: 002,
            project_title: "Project Title",
            type: "Graphic Design",
            deadline: "Jan. 2, 2015",
            billable_hrs: 11,
            hourly_rate: 42.50,
            external_cost: 33.99,
            tax: .6,
        }, ],
    }, // End Customer
    // Start Customer  
    {
        customer: "John Franklin",
        phone: "555.555.5551",
        email: "jfranklin@franks.com",
        // start address strings 
        address: {
            line1: "Road or Po Box",
            city: "Glenvilles",
            state: "West Carolina",
            zip: 45648,
        },
        proposals: [{
            project_title: "Project Title",
            type: "Graphic Design",
            deadline: "Jan. 2, 2015",
            delivery_type: "files",
            problem: "The problem is that the customer has too much crap.",
            notes: "Wants to keep the neon pink color scheme"
        }, {
            project_title: "Project Title II",
            type: "Web Design",
            deadline: "Jan. 22, 2015",
            delivery_type: "online",
            problem: "Another prject",
            notes: "Wants neon green with the neon pink on a digital screen"
        }],
        quotes: [{
            quote_num: 001,
            project_title: "Project Title  - Quote",
            type: "Graphic Design",
            deadline: "Jan. 2, 2015",
            billable_hrs: 11,
            hourly_rate: 42.50,
            external_cost: 33.99,
            tax: .6,
        }, ];
    }, // End Customer
    ];

})();
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="CustomerCtrl as cust" >
    <h2> Customers </h2>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Customer</th>
          <th>Phone</th> 
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Proposals</th>
          <th>Quotes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in cust.customers">
          <td> {{customer.customer}}</td>
          <td> {{customer.phone}} </td>
          <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
          <td>
              <ul class="address"> 
                <li> {{customer.address.line1}} </li> 
                <li> {{customer.address.city}}, {{customer.address.state }} , {{customer.address.zip}}</li>
              </ul> 
          </td>
          <td>
             <ul >
                <li ng-repeat="prop in customer.proposals">{{prop.project_title}}</li>
             </ul>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ul >
                <li ng-repeat="quote in customer.quotes ">{{quote.quote_num}}</li>
             </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  <div>
  <form novalidate class="simple-form" ng-submit="cust.AddCustomer(new)">
    <h2> Add A Customer</h2>
    <label> Customer Name:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="customer" /><br />
     <label>Customer Email:</label> <input type="email" ng-model="email" /><br />
     <label>Customer Phone:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="phone" /><br />
     <label>Customer Address:</label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="line1" placeholder="Address/ PO Box"/><br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="city"placeholder="City" /><br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="state" placeholder="State"/><br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="zip" placeholder="Zip" /><br /><br/>
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button> 
  </form>
</div>

  <div class="newCustomerData"> 
    <h2> The Customer Your Adding: </h2>
    <div><strong>Name:</strong> {{customer}} </div>
    <div><strong>Email:</strong> {{email}} </div>
    <div><strong>Phone:</strong> {{phone}} </div>
    <div><strong>Address:</strong> {{line1}}<br/> {{city}}, {{state}} {{zip}} </div>
  </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: I edited, the question.  Please let me know if that helps, if not I will do my best to add more.  Thanks for your time. @PSL

Comment: Sure. Looks fine now. Check your console for errors. You are missing `new.` in your ng-model bindings. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bypzve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passing AddCustomer(new), but your form isn't collecting input into a 'new' object.
Try adjusting your ng-models to have a dot on a 'new' object:

```
 <label> Customer Name:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="new.customer" /><br />
 <label>Customer Email:</label> <input type="email" ng-model="new.email" /><br />
 <label>Customer Phone:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="new.phone" /><br />
 <label>Customer Address:</label> 
<input type="text" ng-model="new.line1" placeholder="Address/ PO Box"/><br />
<input type="text" ng-model="new.city"placeholder="City" /><br />
<input type="text" ng-model="new.state" placeholder="State"/><br />
<input type="text" ng-model="new.zip" placeholder="Zip" /><br /><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs on the form binding scope level JavaScript objects which are not there and you are trying to get the data from **newcust** object
 Add newcust. to your ng-model in your form

Use this

```
<input type="email" ng-model="newcust.email" />
```

Instead of this

```
<input type="email" ng-model="email" />
```

And for address field you need to add newcust.address like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newcust.address.line1" placeholder="Address/ PO Box"/><br />
```